# How do I build my .NET 8 MAUI iOS app using Xcode 15 in Azure DevOps?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, maui, .net-8.0

When building my .NET 8 iOS MAUI app in an Azure DevOps build pipeline, it complains that I'm not using the latest Xcode.

```
        
ILLink : iOS error IL7000: An error occured while executing the custom linker steps. Please review the build log for more information. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-iOS]
/Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/dotnet/ios/generated-sources/UIKit/UIApplication.g.cs(95): error MT4162: The type 'UIKit.UISceneSessionActivationRequest' (used as a parameter in UIKit.UIApplication.ActivateSceneSession) is not available in iOS 16.4 (it was introduced in iOS 17.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode). [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-iOS]
        
ILLINK : error MT2362: The linker step 'Registrar' failed during processing: The type 'UIKit.UISceneSessionActivationRequest' (used as a parameter in UIKit.UIApplication.ActivateSceneSession) is not available in iOS 16.4 (it was introduced in iOS 17.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode). [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-iOS]
```

I've set up my build pipeline to use `macos-latest` but Xcode 15 does not appear to be installed.

Note: I ran into this problem at work and have resolved it, so I'll include my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of December 2023, the `macos-latest` image is Mac OS 12. The list of build agents along with their image names is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

| Image | Classic Editor Agent Specification | YAML VM Image Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows Server 2022 with Visual Studio 2022 | windows-2022 | windows-latest OR windows-2022 |
| Windows Server 2019 with Visual Studio 2019 | windows-2019 | windows-2019 |
| Ubuntu 22.04 | ubuntu-22.04 | ubuntu-latest OR ubuntu-22.04 |
| Ubuntu 20.04 | ubuntu-20.04 | ubuntu-20.04 |
| macOS 13 Ventura | macOS-13 | macOS-13 |
| macOS 12 Monterey | macOS-12 | macOS-latest OR macOS-12 |
| macOS 11 Big Sur | macOS-11 | macOS-11 |

## Step 1 - Use the *actual* latest image `macos-13`

It's in preview as of right now, but it has latest versions of Xcode (15.0 and 15.0.1) installed.

```
pool:
  vmImage: "macos-13"
```

## Step 2 - Select Xcode version

I have some yaml in my build pipeline that lists out relevant information and selects the latest version of Xcode that I want to use.

```
  - script: |
     echo Mac OS version:
     sw_vers -productVersion
     echo
     echo Installed Xcode versions:
     ls /Applications | grep 'Xcode'
     echo
     echo currently selected xcode:
     xcrun xcode-select --print-path
     echo
     echo selecting latest xcode...
     sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app
     xcrun xcode-select --print-path
     xcodebuild -version
    displayName: Select Xcode Version
```

Example output:

```
Starting: Select Xcode Version
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.231.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/_temp/bb313650-3256-4f80-b567-0ec926cb9c07.sh
Mac OS version:
13.6

Installed Xcode versions:
Xcode.app
Xcode_14.1.0.app
Xcode_14.1.app
Xcode_14.2.0.app
Xcode_14.2.app
Xcode_14.3.1.app
Xcode_14.3.app
Xcode_15.0.1.app
Xcode_15.0.app

currently selected xcode:
/Applications/Xcode_14.3.1.app/Contents/Developer

selecting latest xcode...
/Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app/Contents/Developer
Xcode 15.0.1
Build version 15A507
Finishing: Select Xcode Version
```

Comment: Frustratingly this image doesn't actually have dotnet8 SDK on it

Comment: So what i've worked out is that there are ARM64 mac images that have net8.0 installed on them, however i've not seen one of those allocated to me.

Comment: @RhysBevilaqua put the UseDotNet@2 task in your pipeline

  # Using .NET
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: "sdk"
      version: "8.0.x"
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

Comment: Never copy pictures of text; they purposely exclude people with visual limitations, not to mention people behind restrictive company proxies. I took the 2 minutes to copy from the source site and clean up your answer, please do the same in future.

Comment: Not trying to purposely/intentionally exclude anyone.  Guess that makes "accidentally" a better word? Nonetheless, noted for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution effectively ensures that the correct Xcode version 15.0.1 is used during the build process, allowing your .NET 8 iOS MAUI app to compile without encountering errors related to unavailable types from older iOS SDKs.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

variables:
    BuildConfiguration: Release
    DotNetVersion: 8.x
    iOSVersion: net8.0-ios

pool:
  vmImage: "macos-13"
  demands: xcode

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Select Xcode Version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app
```

Comment: thank you, it helped to resolve the issue